# Filter SQL query results by shared data values, similar to iTunes Get Info

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to do an SQl query (MS Access) and have only the `Like` fields returned, similar to in iTunes, where you can select multiple songs and then, when editing their respective data, you can filter out data that is not shared by each selected song.

For example, I have a table similar to

```
ID,date,weight,buyerid
123,21/07/2014,5,22
124,21/07/2014,5,23
125,22/08/2014,5,23
```

If I search for like results for all three of the IDs (`123`, `124`, and `125`), I would only receive data under the `weight` column, as all three selections have the same `weight`. Likewise, if I searched using `ID`s `123` and `124`, the `date` and `weight` values would be returned, as both `ID`s share those data values. The non-similar data would return `null` or no result.

Is this possible in a single query at all?

EDIT:
rephrase (trying my best to explain) ... I want to search a table of data (multiple fields) and only receive one row of results. Normally a similar search would return multiple rows with some fields containing the same data and others not, but I would like it filtered to return only one row that contains data in each field that is the same across all results (or nothing if not the same).

My other option is to loop through a standard query and pull all data out that matches for each field but i was hoping it might be able to be done in a single SQL query.

Hope that is better.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question a little bit? I'm having a hard time understanding what your actual question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this (assuming your table is named Table1):

```
SELECT  t1.SharedAttributes
FROM
(
        SELECT  ID, CStr([Weight]) AS SharedAttributes
        FROM    Table1
        WHERE   ID IN (123, 124)

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  ID, CStr([Date]) AS SharedAttributes
        FROM    Table1
        WHERE   ID IN (123, 124)
) t1,
(
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS DistinctIDs
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Table1 WHERE ID IN (123, 124))
) t2
GROUP BY t1.SharedAttributes, t2.DistinctIDs
HAVING COUNT(*) = t2.DistinctIDs;
```

This produces:

```
SharedAttributes
21/07/2014
5
```

While:

```
SELECT  t1.SharedAttributes
FROM
(
        SELECT  ID, CStr([Weight]) AS SharedAttributes
        FROM    Table1
        WHERE   ID IN (123, 124, 125)

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  ID, CStr([Date]) AS SharedAttributes
        FROM    Table1
        WHERE   ID IN (123, 124, 125)
) t1,
(
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS DistinctIDs
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Table1 WHERE ID IN (123, 124, 125))
) t2
GROUP BY t1.SharedAttributes, t2.DistinctIDs
HAVING COUNT(*) = t2.DistinctIDs;
```

produces:

```
SharedAttributes
5
```

Code is a bit ugly having the same WHERE clauses multiple times, but I don't think it can be helped.  Another way to do it would be to drop all the searched IDs into a table, and instead of WHERE clauses, INNER JOIN to the table in each query.  Also, a caveat: because you want all the results in one column, we have to cast all the values to a common datatype; in this case, string.

Comment: that appears to do the trick. unfortunately its probably just as cumbersome as looping all results in my code. ill have a bit more of a play but that is what i was after. cheers

Comment: @SteveJohnston: No worries.  I think a set-based solution like this, 99/100, is better than a cursor based one, although the point is taken of how you will produce this.  Could be dynamic SQL just filling in the IDs.  I think the table of values with INNER JOINs has a lot of potential, but not sure if you want to implement that.  Still, though, especially if you are dealing with lots of different IDs, the set-based solution will pay dividends.  I will have a think overnight to see if this can be done more cleanly.

Comment: thanks you very much. unfortunately my actual situation is a table with a couple of dozen fields that need to be included (not just the ones in the example) so it immediately becomes more complex. though i agree this would probably still be the best way to go. i will see how i do with a dynamic build of the sql string and go from there